# hosts file but for whole network?

Tags: networking, dns, hosts-file

I can't believe I can't find this after an hour of Google. This has go to be simple!

On my PC, I edit HOSTS file so say, for example, domain.com goes to local IP 192.168.1.5

Great, that's fine.  But if I want everyone on the network to do the same thing... well, that's a lot of repetition.  Each PC, each laptop, phone, etc.

How can I do that at the network level?

This is a home environment and I have a consumer router that doesn't appear to have any useful option in that regard.

I have a home server that handles multiple roles.  It runs Ubuntu 18.04

I *think* the answer is to set my Ubuntu machine up as a DNS server.  Is that right?  If so, do I then have to point each device to that server?  I see my router DOES have the ability to define the DNS server so can I do it there only?

I don't want to go down a rabbit hole where my new shiny DNS server is something i have to maintain.  Ie. I don't want to be responsible for telling all my computers where to go when Google decides to get a new IP address.  I just want this for internal use.

Thanks.

Comment: You can set up a local DNS server to service requests for the domains you want to manage locally and forward all other requests to DNS servers on the internet.

Comment: DNS system is distributed. A server only answers domains it is responsible to, other requests are forwarded to the next DNS server configured. Hence if Google.com changes it's IP you don't have to care.

Answer (score 3):

> I think the answer is to set my Ubuntu machine up as a DNS server. Is that right?

Yes, you need to set up a DNS server. (Though the DNS server isn't required to be *on* the Ubuntu machine – it can be anywhere you want, even on a remote location.)

In this case, make sure your chosen DNS server software can act as a recursive resolver. (For example, BIND and Unbound will work fine, whereas NSD or Knot are "authoritative-only" and won't be able to work as the LAN's primary DNS server.)

*Some* consumer routers actually have a built-in DNS server for this exact purpose, but it's often limited to just hostnames under some ".home" or ".lan" domain, so running your own might be a better idea.

> do I then have to point each device to that server? I see my router DOES have the ability to define the DNS server so can I do it there only?

Yes, and yes, the router's settings will be picked up by all devices which use DHCP.

> I don't want to go down a rabbit hole where my new shiny DNS server is something i have to maintain. Ie. I don't want to be responsible for telling all my computers where to go when Google decides to get a new IP address. I just want this for internal use.

DNS has been built specifically so that resolvers wouldn't need to do this, just like your ISP's DNS servers do not need to do this, and neither do public DNS servers nor anyone else.

A DNS resolver does not hold a massive database of the world's domains. It only needs to know addresses of the [*root* nameservers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_name_server#Root_server_addresses) –  the 13 of them change addresses so rarely that even a list from 1990 would still work in a pinch (C-root has been at 192.33.4.12 for a very long time). Usually the list is even embedded into the software so no configuration is needed. From there, the resolver can work out which nameservers host the `com` TLD and which nameservers host the `google.com` domain and so on.

Though your DNS server doesn't *have* to do all of that by itself – it can just forward the query to another server, the one that you would normally use, and let it handle the work. It is perfectly fine to configure e.g. 8.8.8.8 as a "forwarder" or "upstream" in your BIND config.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you help me fill in some blanks?  I had trouble understanding Bind so I installed dnsmasq which seems more simple. Is this OK?  I followed instructions and I got to the point where a "host myhost.company 192.168.30.103" command (run from that same server) works insofar as I get a result.  But I certainly can't ping myhost.company from any computer on my network or even from the server.  What am I missing?

Comment: Does at least "nslookup myhost.company" work? Are other computers configured to use 192.168.30.103 as DNS server already? (ping will only work successfully if myhost.company is allowed to respond to ICMP requests.)